# How to choose the threshold of the output of a dnn in tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow

I am currently learning to make neural networks with tensorflow. And the library provides a very convenient way to create one with the estimator DNNClassifier like in this tutorial: https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/premade_estimators.

However, I don't manage to see how to choose the final treshold of the output layer before making the prediction:

For instance, let's say we have a binary classifier between 'KO' and 'OK'. The end of the neural network compute the probabilities for each possibility for a specific sample, for instance [0.4,0.6] (so 40% that the answer is 'KO' and 60% that the answer is 'OK'). I assume that the dnn takes by default a threshold of 0.5, so it will answer 'OK' here. But I want to change this threshold to 0.8 so that if the dnn is not sure at 80% for 'OK', it will answer 'KO' (in order to tune the FP-rate and the FN-rate).
How can we do that ?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The premade estimators are somewhat rigid. The `DNNClassifier`, for example, does not provide a mechanism to change the loss function or to obtain the logits/probabilities output by the classifier, as you've discovered.

To modify the logic of how predictions are generated, or to modify your loss function, you'll have to create a custom `Estimator`. [This tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/custom_estimators) walks you through that process.

If you haven't invested too much time learning how to use the `Estimator` API yet, I recommend you also acquaint yourself with [Keras](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras), another high-level API for building and training deep learning models in TensorFlow; you might find it easier to build custom models with Keras rather than Estimators.